# Crashed instances stay alive but become unresponsive

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm working on an OSX project in Xcode and occasionally the app will crash. After crashing, Xcode no longer has a reference to the instance so I can start a new one, however, the crashed instance is still shown in the cmd+tab app switcher. Each subsequent crash results in a new instance that shows up in the app switcher, each of which are entirely unresponsive and do not shown up in activity monitor. The biggest problem is that they prevent restarts and shutting down. What can I do?

Edit: The most recent time I had this issue, killing dock resolved the issue, but this is not always the case.

Comment: File a bug report with Apple...

Comment: @matt I was hoping someone else would respond with more insight, but it looks like I'll just have to file a bug report. Thanks for the help!